# Can a warlock with the UA Raven Queen patron cast spells on targets that they can only see using their Sentinel Raven's sight?

Tags: dnd-5e, unearthed-arcana, vision-and-light, targeting, spellcasting

A [Warlock Pact with the Raven Queen](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/20170213_Wizrd_Wrlck_UAv2_i48nf.pdf#page=2) not only grants me a Sentinel Raven, but also the handy ability to see through its eyes.  Unlike the telepathic connection with a regular familiar, I don't have to use an action to do so.

If I am blinded, but my Sentinel Raven is not (and within telepathic range), can I use my raven's sight to cast spells that require me to see my target?
Would this negate any disadvantage resulting from me being blinded? Or would I still suffer disadvantage, for example, because I have to cast from my raven's perspective and not my own point of view?

Comment: Added a link to the UA article in question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you may do this and it would negate the Blinded condition for you. The UA states:

> You can see through the raven's eyes and hear what it hears while it is within 100 feet of you.

The raven can act as your eyes and ears, giving you hearing and sight when you may not have it. However, you are NOT casting your spells through the raven (as is possible with a familiar.) Therefore casting ranges would still be from your character and not the raven.

Strategic Notes:

1. Sentinel raven grants YOU darkvision. It does not have that ability itself and it's vision requires light.
2. The Sentinel Raven would be acting as your eyes and ears. Keeping those protected should be a priority. If the raven stays on your shoulder, it:

   > can't be targeted by any attack or other harmful effect; only can cast spells on it; it can't take damage; [but] it is incapacitated.

Comment: I, personally, would be a little more stringent than that. I'd rule that the Raven had to be sharing your position to allow you to aim a spell properly. Aiming while using a third person perspective is hard (you can try it in a video game that has a free camera mode). But, per the RAW, this is probably correct.

Comment: @guildsbounty Definitely an interesting way to look at it, but it's also very much in the Warlock's advantage to keep it on their shoulder since it can't be targeted by any attacks/be damaged or incapacitated while it's there. Keep those eyes and ears protected!

Comment: @KorvinStarmast made it so. Also realized that it's not that it can't incapacitated...but that it IS incapacitated while on your shoulder.

Comment: @guildsbounty except firearms don't use magic sights.