# Does the Bodak's Death Gaze affect someone looking through their familiar's eyes?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, familiars, unearthed-arcana

The Sentinal Raven grants the character the ability to see through its eyes:

> "You can see through the raven's eyes and hear what it hears while it is within 100 feet of you."

The Bodak's Death Gaze ability

> When a creature that can see the bodak's eyes starts its turn within 30 feet of the bodak, the bodak can force it to make a DC 13 Constitution saving throw if the bodak isn't incapacitated and can see the creature... Unless surprised, a creature can avert its eyes to avoid the saving throw at the start of its turn. If the creature does so, it has disadvantage on attack rolls against the bodak until the start of its next turn. If the creature looks at the bodak in the meantime, it must immediately make the saving throw.

So, if the Warlock is within 30 feet and averts his gaze, but the Raven does not, will the Warlock be forced to make the saving throw? [This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/97536/25433) leads me to believe that the Warlock would be able to target the Bodak, but does that count as "looking at" the Bodak for purposes of the saving throw?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### The Warlock could target the Bodak using the raven's sight, but would still be a valid target for Death Gaze

There are two criteria for the Bodak's attack to work: the target must be able to see the Bodak's eyes, and the target must start its turn within 30 feet of the Bodak. The distance criterion is met, so the ability triggers if the Warlock can see the Bodak's eyes.

The attack makes no stipulations regarding *how* a target sees the Bodak's eyes, so it would seem the criterion cannot be circumvented in this manner through RAW means.

Comment: I feel like this answer is missing the intent of the question. I have edited the question to clarify the positioning of the Warlock.

Comment: @Destruktor Edited, though pretty much the same answer

Comment: I think this is a valid answer. Bodacs ability sena to work even thru mirrors

Comment: @GarretGang Interesting. Is that in one of the rulebooks or elsewhere? I'd consider adding a note about this to the body of my answer if it's mentioned in an official source.

Comment: Raw "of you can see the Bodacs eyes." Medusa ability in 5e works thru mirrors as well "if the Medusa sees it's own reflection it must make a con save to avoid being petrified." So I am assuming that this as with eyebite as the Medusa's stare relies on vision rather then an unblocked straight line

Comment: The Medusa's ability is implied to swirl thru mirrors. The sizing is the sabre as that of the Bodacs so I thought that I'd would apply

Answer (score 0):

"Unless surprised, a creature can avert its eyes to avoid the saving throw at the start of its turn."

I would consider the Warlock's eyes to be averted..... 
Mirrors are one thing, but thats an entirely different thing, you are literally having to send the magical affect over the link between him and him familiar.

The fact it specifically requires the 'eyes to not be averted' does imply that it requires the light based connection between the two.

However, it would still have full affect on the Raven.