# How does you seeing through a creature's eyes work exactly?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

If you can see through another creature's eyes (such as a familiar or projected image), can you cast a spell which specifies "a creature you can see in range" on a creature you see through another creatures's eyes?

Comment: You need to tell us what game you are playing!

Comment: Fixed. Sorry forgot to add that.

Comment: Great, but the correct way to do this is with the tag system. Fixed that for you.

Comment: *a creature you see through it's eyes?* Can you explain what you mean by that?  Is this a telepathy thing, or another spell/class ability that allows you to look at a creature through its own eyes?

Comment: Also, if you're asking what I think you're asking, it might be a duplicate of [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/97536/15469) question.

Comment: Or [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/51240/15469) question.

Comment: Yes, those answer my question Miniman, Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Maybe

It depends on the specific spell and the way that it is worded.

If the spell requires a target "that you can see" it doesn't matter how you see it so using another creature's eyes would qualify as would scrying magic.

However, you are still bound by the other constraints of the spell. These include:

- Range (PHB p.201): This is measured from *the caster*, not the point of view,
- A Clear Path to the Target (PHB p.204): The default for *all* spells is there must be a clear path from *the caster* to the target.
- Action: Many effects that allow you to use another creature's eyes involve using your action. This limits your spell to bonus action or reaction casting time spells unless you have another action available (e.g. *Haste*).